# parse decoded json array into csv

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb, csv

I have a file that contains millions of arrays of this size:

```
{
  "leagues" : [{
      "tier" : "SILVER",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "359",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "TryHard",
          "division" : "II",
          "leaguePoints" : "63",
          "wins" : "65"
        }],
      "id" : "359"
    }],
  "summonerId" : "359",
  "region" : "euw",
  "updatedAt" : "1412122432"
},
```

That's, for example, the smallest array.,There are some arrays that have additional linked arrays that contain extra information in relation to the primary array. Example:

```
{
  "summonerId" : "477",
  "region" : "euw",
  "leagues" : [{
      "tier" : "GOLD",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "477",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "Alucard662545",
          "division" : "V",
          "leaguePoints" : "9",
          "wins" : "128"
        }]
    }, {
      "tier" : "SILVER",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "TEAM-8d6a3640-2da8-11e2-99dc-782bcb4ce61a",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "CAPCOMP BE",
          "division" : "V",
          "leaguePoints" : "0",
          "wins" : "24"
        }]
    }, {
      "tier" : "BRONZE",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "TEAM-8d6a3640-2da8-11e2-99dc-782bcb4ce61a",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "CAPCOMP BE",
          "division" : "I",
          "leaguePoints" : "55",
          "wins" : "8"
        }]
    }],
  "updatedAt" : "1410786559"
},
```

I have been literally pulling hair out of my head, spend 2 day and nights to figure it out. I have MongoDB where this information is stored in, when I export it I can only get decoded JSON arrays. I need this stuff to be fully CSV formatted. How name can I CSV format a million arrays like these?

Comment: other than column separators, csv has no "format". there's no provision for nested records. there's just columns. And since you've provided **NO** details about how you want your csv to look like, we can't help you - even if someone did feel like writing the code for you. We're here to HELP, not do your job for you.

Comment: A bit harsh Mark B, but @floppy floppy to your question, I think you may have to consider creating a csv string using java script and loop through your current js object to extract then add to your csv string. Has that crossed your mind? I would start with a smaller data set to test, obviously.

Comment: I did not find Marc's matter-of-fact and true statement to be harsh @Mr.Concolato.

Comment: I understand marc b, could you please point me where i clearly stated that i wanted the community to fix this? Im for sure that i was asking how this could be achieved. By helping people could provide new ways of thinking that i couldve been missing, or a piece of code that did the trick for a similar situation. You are not helping me with your comment, but thanks for sharing your opinion. Have a nice day sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

[mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/) is a utility that produces a JSON or CSV export of data stored in a MongoDB instance. Usage example:

```
mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --csv --fieldFile fields.txt --out /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

which takes the fields specified in the \r-terminated fields.txt file, one per line, from the collection `contacts` and puts them into /opt/backups/contacts.csv.

Any other way to read in JSON to a language and write csv. An example in python follows:

```
from pymongo import  MongoClient
import csv
client = MongoClient()
db = client['test-database']
collection = db.test_collection
writer = csv.writer('/opt/backups/contacts.csv')
writer.writerow([k for k in collection])
writer writerows([[v for v in c] for c in collection])
```

... and does the same Hope that helps.